# Segmentation fault while initializing variable with constant

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I got a strange segmentation fault. For debugging I rewrote my code so that some values are constant, but the segmentation fault remains. At this point I have no idea what could be causing this fault.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  findMaxFlowInSTNetwork (graph=0xbfb74076, adj=0xbfaaccf4, source=1, target=2, 
    maxValue=2) at invariants/connectivity/multi_connectivity.c:36
36      int order = 4;
(gdb) print order
Cannot access memory at address 0xbbd980c4
```

I've never had a segmentation fault like this. Does anybody have an idea what might be causing this and how to remedy it?

Edit:

Here is the code of that function:

```
//returns the minimum of the maxflow of the st-network and maxValue
int findMaxFlowInSTNetwork(GRAPH graph, ADJACENCY adj, int source, int target, int maxValue){
    int order = 4;
    //int order = graph[0][0];
    int paths[(MAXN+1)*(MAXN+1)] = {0};
    int pathCount = 0;
    boolean currentPath[MAXN+1] = {0};
    while(findPath(graph, adj, source, target, paths, order, currentPath) && pathCount < maxValue){
        pathCount++;
    }
    return pathCount;
 }
```

The line in comments is the original line. Since this was giving a segmentation fault, I replaced it by the line `int order = 4;`. I call this function like this:

```
minimumCutSize = minDegree;
for (i = 1; i <= graph[0][0]; i++){
    if(i!=vertexMinDegree){
        minimumCutSize = findMaxFlowInSTNetwork(graph, adj, vertexMinDegree, i, minimumCutSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: show code where this seg fault occurs

Comment: Can you show the function, and how you call it?

Comment: Yes, I will add that code.

Comment: What is the value of MAXN, and what is the size of GRAPH? consider get parameter as const GRAPH& (const reference) intstead of GRAPH to save memory.

Comment: Ah, I just saw that MAXN is set to 4000 where I thought it was only 100. Maybe that is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack for a process is usually in the single-digit megabyte range, and with `MAXN` set to 4000 you will have an array (`paths`) taking well over 60 MB! Definitely a case of stack overflow!

Either adjust the size (by quite a bit) or allocate it dynamically of the heap.

Comment: Uhu, it is a rewrite of an old Java program I wrote. I definitely still need to tweak the memory usage. I never knew that stack overflow errors manifested themselves like this. Guess I've always been careful enough in the past. ;-) Thanks.